# How do you disable client-side validation in .NET Core Razor pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, kendo-ui

I have the below view model. Nothing is marked as required but I can't submit the form it's attached to as it always complains a required field has not been filled out. This occurs even if I fill out all available fields. The controls the model is bound to are kendo controls. I'm not sure if that has any effect.

```
public class EmployeePlanAttributesModel
{
    public int EmployeeAttributesId { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public decimal? Rate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EffectiveDate { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to disable client-side validation in javascript?

I tried using this in the document ready function but it didn't work:

```
$('#EffectiveDate').rules('remove');
$('#Rate').rules('remove');
```

Answer (score 1):

In razor pages,for disable client-side validation.Use this:-

```
services.Configure<HtmlHelperOptions>(o => o.ClientValidationEnabled = false);
```

See this [Documantation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0#disable-client-side-validation)

Comment: I only want to disable it for this one screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try making the model properties nullable.

```
public class ModelWithNullable
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
    }
```

I am also using two validations. JavaScript validation in view

```
<form method="post">

    <!--Name-->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="MyProperty.Name"></label>
        <input asp-for="MyProperty.Name" class="form-control" />
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MyProperty.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
    <!--Description-->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="MyProperty.Date"></label>
        <input asp-for="MyProperty.Date" class="form-control" />
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MyProperty.Date, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>


</form>

@section Scripts {
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />

}
```

and ModelState in OnPost

```
 if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return RedirectToPage("/Index");
            }
```

and it works properly. Returns Model with date null.  Just remember to do the null check when displaying the model, otherwise, you will get an exception.

Comment: Is this behavior referenced in the official documentation?

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: @OneNeptune https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-properties?tabs=data-annotations%2Cwithout-nrt#conventions

Answer (score 0):

As no answer is marked correct I wanna give it a shot .

It could have been you have a form and the html mentions the input to be say date

```
<input type="date" ....
```

Which make the browser do the validation!

Comment: No, the OP is specifically asking about validation enforced by ASP.NET. This invoives various `data-` attributes, and is over and above validation perormed by HTML5-compliant browsers on `input` types